# IN Query Google App Engine Datastore Java With Preference of Sorting Based on Number of matching keywords in list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We have the tags in the datastore in kind as column and it has list of tag words and we want to filter the datastore matching or case and sort it based on the number of matching keywords

How can we do this in app engine query platform Java, Please help us if you have any idea.

Please find the model

Consider model

```
public class Car {

  String id;  

  String name;

  String model;

  String manufacture;

  int year;

  List<String> tags;

}
```

same thing for DB structure too,

```
List<String> searchKeyword =  Arrays.asList(q.split(","));

Query query = new Query("Car");
query.setFilter(new FilterPredicate("tags",FilterOperation.IN,searchKeyword);
List<Entity> entities = ds.prepare(query).asList(withLimit(10));
```

In this case for example, q = royal,coupe

result should match both the keywords show come in the top
and in one keyword should be followed.

Caterham 7 - one keyword 
Nissan 370Z - match two keyword

output 
Nissan 370z
Caterham 7

Same thing for news belongs to the cars model also has tags
and search should work there also same way

News will have title,description,tags,images,video

Thanks
Krishnan

Comment: It sounds from your example that this is not possible using the Datastore, however I would recommend updating your question to include a code sample of your model definition and an example of the output you are expecting.

Comment: Also another note about your tags listed: Are you running on App Engine or are you using the Google Cloud Datastore? If you are running on App Engine, the Java API does not have GQL support, so you're probably not looking for a gql-based answer.

Comment: Hi Patrick,Thanks for you comments, I have updated the Post and I am not expecting GQL solution, I want it in Java Preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively in the datastore. The way IN works in the Datastore is that it issues one query for each item in your list, then provides the union of the results (really it is [using disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) ([App Engine source code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QuerySplitHelper.java?r=270))).

Instead, you could issues the queries yourself to guarantee the order you want (first query for results that match N tags using an AND filter, then N-1, then N-2, ...).

For two tags, this would look like:

```
List<String> searchKeyword = Arrays.asList(q.split(","));

Query query = new Query("Car");
query.setFilter(CompositeFilter.and(Arrays.asList(
    new FilterPredicate("tags", FilterOperation.EQUAL, searchKeyword.get(0)),
    new FilterPredicate("tags", FilterOperation.EQUAL, searchKeyword.get(1)))));

List<Entity> entities = ds.prepare(query).asList(withLimit(10));

query.setFilter(CompositeFilter.or(Arrays.asList(
    new FilterPredicate("tags", FilterOperation.EQUAL, searchKeyword.get(0)),
    new FilterPredicate("tags", FilterOperation.EQUAL, searchKeyword.get(1)))));
entities.addAll(ds.prepare(query).asList(withLimit(10));
```

Obviously, this will only work for two tags, but can be generalized for more than that. You should probably also use the [async API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async#Async_Queries) so that you can issue all the queries in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for you response, this sound good, Here when we go for pagination, this will cause one issues. I need to manage the count of each AND matching keywords combinations and based on that I should query or logic.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Could you please help approach is right or wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246133/index-builder-for-fast-retrieval-similar-multiple-table-retrieval-in-single-quer

Comment: Hi Patrick, There was some tricky thing, in this I need to keep track of all the id which matches the AND result and need to add not equal filter to avoid or matches returning the same result in the pagination, is there any other ways we can do that combining both the query in single one thanks